# Is this measure called anything?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Well, I do not know if this is formally a measure, but imagine $f(\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2)$:
$$f(\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2) = \|\mathbf v_1 - \mathbf v_2\|_{\ell_0}$$
where $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2$ are two vectors of equal size and $\|\cdot\|_{\ell_0}$ is the $l_0$ "pseudo-norm", i.e. $\|\mathbf v\|_{\ell_0} = |v_1|^0 + |v_2|^0 + \ldots + |v_\text{last}|^0$.

This "measure" counts the number of non-zero entries in the difference $\mathbf v_1 - \mathbf v_2$ - the number of positions in which the two vectors differ.

Does this have a known name? The reason I am asking is that it is similar to Hamming distance but operates on vector entries rather than individual bits.

Comment: I believe "metric" would be a better word than "measure" to describe this.

Answer (score 2):

I am having trouble finding a reference.  However, this "norm" is indeed well known, and it is indeed referred to as either the "zero-norm" or the "$L0$-norm".  Note that this norm obeys [the separation and triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) conditions of a norm, but fails in absolute homogeneity.

This "norm" gets a lot of use in the context of compressed sensing and sparse recovery, a field with a lot of active research.

Comment: I was thinking of $f$ here, not the not-quite-norm.

Comment: There's not much of a distinction between the situations where you'd use one as opposed to the other, so I highly doubt that your $f$ doesn't have its own distinct name.  A sensible name for it is "the metric induced by the $0$-norm", since given any norm, you can find a metric (distance function) just as you found your $f$.